# malloc: *** error for object 0x120e06884: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c

I have written some code on to find the number of times the characters repeated in the string.Considered 2 pointers and allocated memory dynamically, then input the string into one of the pointers.Then copying the characters without redundancies into the another pointer and finally comparing it, incrementing the count and printing to the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void string_cpy(char *from, char *to);
int len(char *p);

int main()
{
    char *name, *copy, *hold;
    int i, j, lent, count = 0, length;

    name = (char *)calloc(25, sizeof(char));
    copy = (char *)calloc(25, sizeof(char));

    printf("Give a string:");
    scanf("%s", name);
    puts("");

    string_cpy(name, copy);
    hold = name;
    lent = len(copy);   //l=4
    length = len(name); //lenght = 5
    printf("Characters and their corresponding frequencies\n");

    for (i = 0; i < lent; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < length;)
        {
            if (*(copy) == *(name))
            {
                ++count;
                ++name;
                ++j;
            }
            else
            {
                ++j;
                ++name;
            }
        }
        name = hold;
        printf("%c-%d\n", *(copy), count);
        count = 0;
        ++copy;
    }

    free(name);
    free(copy);

    return 0;
}

void string_cpy(char *from, char *to)
{
    int i, j, k, l, ex;
    char key;
    l = len(from); //l=5
    char *t = to;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < l; ++i)
    {
        key = *(from + i);
        ex = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < i; ++k)
        {
            if (*(to + k) == key)
            {
                ex = 1;
            }
        }
        if (!ex)
        { //if(ex==0)
            strcpy((to + j), (from + i));
            ++j;
        }
    }
}

int len(char *p)
{
    int leng = 0;
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        ++leng;
        ++p;
    }
    return leng;
}
```

when I try to free() up both the pointers or the `'''char *copy'''` it throws me an error
->malloc: *** error for object 0x120e06884: pointer being freed was not allocated
->malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

This was done on my Mac OS

Comment: For example you are changing the pointer name in main ++name;. So after that the pointer does not point to the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the value of the `calloc`ed pointer. It does not reference anymore the allocated memory block.

```
++copy;
```

Comment: then won't the memory be wasted? what happens to the pointer? A little more specific could be appreciated. Also this problem is only experienced on Mac but not on windows and why is that?

Comment: @SushanthAmbati Simply you need to keep the reference of the allocated memory block and pass this reference to free. There is nothing to be more "specific".

Comment: @SushanthAmbati every pointer returned by `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc` must be freed by a call to `free`. If you pass anything else than a pointer returned by one of  these three functions, you get undefined behaviour (mostly crashes, or other error messages).